# Running an awk by splitting the lines

Tags: shell, awk

This is such a basic question in awk . But I am facing issues in this and I dont know why. problem is when I run the awk command in a single line such as

```
awk 'BEGIN {} {print $0;}' FILE
```

Then the code is running perfecctly

But if I split the code between lines such as

```
 awk '
 BEGIN
 {
 }
 {
      print $0;
 }' FILE
```

It gives me an error stating that **BEGIN should have an action part** . I was wondering since it is the same code that I am formatting, why am I getting this error. Its really important for me to solve this as I would be writting large lines of codes in awk it would be difficult for me to format and bring it in a single line everytime. Could you ppl please help me regarding this. Thank you. Note. I am running this awk in shell environment

Comment: If you don't need any code in your BEGIN block, you should delete it. Else ... believe what the error messages are telling you! ;-) Try `awk 'BEGIN  {}; {print $0;}' FILE` to see if that genterates the error message. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `'{' right after the`BEGIN` and you will *not* get the error message.

The opening paren `{` for `BEGIN` needs to be on the `same` line as `BEGIN`. So change what you have

```
awk '
 BEGIN
 {
```

to

```
awk '
 BEGIN {
```

and you won't get the error message.

The [manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_52.html) does state that "BEGIN and END rules must have actions;", so that may be another problem. This

```
awk 'BEGIN {} ...
```

seems a bit odd to me (and there's really *no* reason to have this if nothing is happening)

@Birei's helpful comment below explains that the way these statements will "parse will be different in both cases. The open `'{'` in next line is parsed as an action without pattern (not related with BEGIN), while in same line means an empty action of the BEGIN rule."

Comment: +1, parse will be different in both cases. The open paren in next line is parsed as an action without pattern (not related with `BEGIN`), while in same line means an empty action of the `BEGIN` rule.

Comment: Of course you can complete your own answer as you wish, don't worry about the credit, I don't mind :-)

Comment: @Birei: It's not an open paren, it's an open curly brace.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I'll make the change, but as someone to whom English isn't their first language, I always thought ([{ are all considered parens, and using square, curly, etc were just qualifiers .. the stuff you can learn on SO .. :)

Comment: In American English, `(` is a parenthesis. In British English, IIRC, it's a "round bracket"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion guys .. So do I have to have the same for the END too .. i.e END { for END /n {

Comment: And also how to represent action part

Comment: @NandaKumar I think that's a fair assumption to make with regard to `END`.